# Cant set attribute after find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to set the attribute of the a element i found with a find()

i tryed this  :

```
$(this).children('a').setAttribute("href","a link");
```

it does find the a element but setAttribute gives me an error?

Comment: `setAttribute()` is a javascript method, not jQuery's one

Comment: yeah my mistake just started programming in javascript and jquery (A)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.attr()` instead of `.setAttribute()`:

```
 $(this).children('a').attr("href","a link");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr()` in jquery.Jquery already have term property named '`attr`'

```
$(this).find('a').attr("href","a link");
```